# How can I show my database recent post to top?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter

My database looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zorkg.png).

In my app, it shows in random order, but I want that the recent add will go to the top.

I try to order by child, but it is not working.

This is the retrieving data code:

```
DatabaseReference playlistsRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Playlists");
playlistsRef.once().then((DataSnapshot snap)
{
  var KEYSplaylists = snap.value.keys;
  var Dataplaylists = snap.value;

  playlistsList.clear();

  for (var individualkeyplaylists in KEYSplaylists) {
    Playlists playlists = new Playlists
      (
        Dataplaylists[individualkeyplaylists]['image'],
        //    DATA[individualkeyplaylists]['playlisturl'],
        //    DATA[individualkeyplaylists]['time'],
        Dataplaylists[individualkeyplaylists]['title'],
        Dataplaylists[individualkeyplaylists]['type'],
        //    DATA[individualkeyplaylists]['userid'],
        Dataplaylists[individualkeyplaylists]['tap'],
      );

    playlistsList.add(playlists);

    setState(() {
      print('Length: $playlistsList.length');
    });
  };
});
```

And the listview builder here

```
 ListView.builder
 (
   itemCount:  playlistsList.length,
   itemBuilder: (_, index) {
     return PlaylistsUI(playlistsList[index].image, playlistsList[index].title, playlistsList[index].type, playlistsList[index].tap,);
   }
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
playlistsList.insert(0, playlists); // Instead of playlistsList.add(playlists);
```

Comment: it doesn't work as expected, the list is reversed now but when I add a new record it doesn't go up like recent but in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `snap.value` returns a map, and the keys/values in a map are by definition not ordered.

In order to maintain the order in which the items come from the database, you'll need to listen to the [`onChild...` events](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/Query/onChildAdded.html) (at least until [`DataSnapshot.forEach` is implemented](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/711)). Those `onChild...` events fire for the individual child nodes, and thus allow you to maintain the correct order. For a (rather complex) implementation of this, have a look at the [`FirebaseSortedList` class](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/6b6c6404715297c8324b57ece5ecf638431bbd9e/packages/firebase_database/lib/ui/firebase_sorted_list.dart) in the FlutterFire library.

Alternatively, you can simply re-sort the nodes in the client. It's a bit of duplicate work, but might be faster to implement.

Comment: Here's a simple example of how to use `onChildAdded`, which will fire in the correct order: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_database/example/lib/main.dart#L80

Comment: Please be more descriptive in your comments, as observing the `onChildAdded` stream is really how to do this. For example, if you've implemented that, update your question to include the minimal code that reproduces the updated problem.

Comment: I don't know how to do this please help me to edit my code for implement onchildAdded

Comment: The problem is that I have a loop that is visible in each path that can be retrieved in List and quickly the list, so I don't see exactly where to implement

Comment: Where I can add onchildAdded?

Comment: Where can I add the onchildAdded ?

Comment: You'd implement the `onChildAdded` listener the way it is shown in the sample I linked, in place of the `playlistsRef.once().then((DataSnapshot snap)` that you now have. The callback will be called for each child node, and the data for that child node will then be in the `event.snapshot` property. Alternatively you can use your current listener, and re-sort the data client-side.